# Push firestore snapshot return into an array

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, jsx

I'm having trouble copying the mapped return of a **onSnapshot** listener from firebase inside an array (But very IMPORTANT : **I don't want to use the state syntax**):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let copyChats = [];
    const unsubscribe = db.collection('chats').onSnapshot(snapshot =>

        (
            console.log(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                    id: doc.id,
                    data: doc.data()
                }
            )))
        )
    )

    return unsubscribe;
}, [])
```

This code returns correctly the content in the console:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "data": Object {
      "chatName": "presidentielle",
    },
    "id": "8DRKgDCW54Zt4yf1anoR",
  },
  Object {
    "data": Object {
      "chatName": "titi",
    },
    "id": "9MudmtUfi9nGiWMpwHGk",
  },
  Object {
    "data": Object {
      "chatName": "essais",
    },
    "id": "Hi5a8FpDaf7EwwwpmOXn",
  },
  Object {
    "data": Object {
      "chatName": "titi",
    },
    "id": "ZnX3jaRkrJN4oiNCC3un",
  },
  Object {
    "data": Object {
      "chatName": "essais",
    },
    "id": "dPruNs46X0jbhr0sL7xk",
  },
  Object {
    "data": Object {
      "chatName": "test chat",
    },
    "id": "vxs7RdSBER83TOCPHko1",
  },
]
Array [
  Object {
    "data": Object {
      "chatName": "presidentielle",
    },
    "id": "8DRKgDCW54Zt4yf1anoR",
  },
  Object {
    "data": Object {
      "chatName": "titi",
    },
    "id": "9MudmtUfi9nGiWMpwHGk",
  },
  Object {
    "data": Object {
      "chatName": "essais",
    },
    "id": "Hi5a8FpDaf7EwwwpmOXn",
  },
  Object {
    "data": Object {
      "chatName": "titi",
    },
    "id": "ZnX3jaRkrJN4oiNCC3un",
  },
  Object {
    "data": Object {
      "chatName": "essais",
    },
    "id": "dPruNs46X0jbhr0sL7xk",
  },
  Object {
    "data": Object {
      "chatName": "test chat",
    },
    "id": "vxs7RdSBER83TOCPHko1",
  },
]
```

But what I want to do is to copy this exact data model in an the array **copyChats**, and I can't do it. I've tried all kinds of **spread** and **push** syntax.

```
   useEffect(() => {
        let copyChats = [];
        const unsubscribe = db.collection('chats').onSnapshot(snapshot =>

            (
                copyChats = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                        id: doc.id,
                        data: doc.data()
                    }
                ))
            )
        )
        console.log(copyChats);
        return unsubscribe;
    }, [])
```

The only thing I'm able to get is an empty array !like the code above which give me this return:

```
Array []
```

If you have any Idea. Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not *where* you access the array, but **when** you access it. If you run the code in a debugger, or add a `console.log("Hello")` inside he call, you'll see that the `console.log(copyChats)` actually runs **before** `copyChats = snapshot.docs.map` ever executes. So that explains why the array is empty: it hasn't been populated yet.

> I don't want to use the state syntax

React's state is precisely the mechanism to pass data that is asynchronously loaded to the UI. If you want to render the data from the database in the UI, using state is the correct approach.

Also see:

- [React native call function in text element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67511389/react-native-call-function-in-text-element/67511632#67511632)
- [React Not Updating Render After SetState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48655464/react-not-updating-render-after-setstate/48655892#48655892)
- [Using Map in React with firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51700376/using-map-in-react-with-firebase/51700476#51700476)

Comment: Thank you. Just figured it out during the afternoon (for the asynchronicity). I had just in mind that the useState reloads the whole file at every change, so I wanted to avoid it. Never mind.